# DEigenvalues with Robin B.C. sign problem

Tags: differential-equations, eigenvalues

To find eigenvalues for $y''=\lambda y$ with robin boundary conditions on one end, and Dirichlet on the other end, I am getting correct value when robin B.C. on the right side, but when I flip things, and put robin on the left side, Mathematica does not give correct eigenvalues. It seems like a sign issue again.

**Robin on the right side**

Finding eigenvalues for
\begin{align*}
y^{\prime\prime}+\lambda y  & =0\\
y^{\prime}\left(  1\right)  +y\left(  1\right)    & =0\\
y(0)  & =0
\end{align*}

Code

```
ClearAll[y,x];
op={-y''[x]+NeumannValue[y[x],x==1],DirichletCondition[y[x]==0,x==0]};
eig=DEigenvalues[op,y[x],{x,0,1},6]//N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The eigenvalues are given by roots of $\tan\sqrt\lambda+\sqrt\lambda$

```
 NSolve[Tan[Sqrt[lam]]+Sqrt[lam]==0&& 0< lam<303,lam]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which is correct.

**Robin on the left side**

Same code as above, just switch the B.C.

\begin{align*}
y^{\prime\prime}+\lambda y  & =0\\
y^{\prime}\left(  0\right)  +y\left(  0\right)    & =0\\
y(1)  & =0
\end{align*}

code

```
ClearAll[y,x];
op={-y''[x]+NeumannValue[y[x],x==0],DirichletCondition[y[x]==0,x==1]};
eig=DEigenvalues[op,y[x],{x,0,1},6]//N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now eigenvalues are roots of $\tan\sqrt\lambda-\sqrt\lambda$

```
 NSolve[Tan[Sqrt[lam]]-Sqrt[lam]==0&& 0<= lam<400,lam]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see they are not the same. By trial and error, I found that changing the code to be

```
op={-y''[x]+NeumannValue[-y[x],x==0],DirichletCondition[y[x]==0,x==1]};
eig=DEigenvalues[op,y[x],{x,0,1},6]//N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now it gives the correct eigenvalues !

Question is: Why with robin on right side `NeumannValue[y[x],x==1]` works  but needed a minus sign when robin on left side `NeumannValue[-y[x],x==0]` ?

This is very confusing. Only reference I saw is http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NeumannValue.html

Where it says

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So following the above, the robin conditions above is $y'(x)=-y(x)$ which means it should be `NeumannValue[-y[x],x==0]`  But if using this convention for first example above will now give wrong result:

```
op={-y''[x]+NeumannValue[-y[x],x==1],DirichletCondition[y[x]==0,x==0]};
eig=DEigenvalues[op,y[x],{x,0,1},6]//N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which is wrong.

So the question is, which is it? `NeumannValue[-y[x],x==location]` or `NeumannValue[y[x],x==location]` ?

Confused about signs.

### Appendix

If you need derivation of eigenvalues, please see below

**Robin on right end:**

Finding eigenvalues for
\begin{align*}
y^{\prime\prime}+\lambda y  & =0\\
y^{\prime}\left(  1\right)  +y\left(  1\right)    & =0\\
y(0)  & =0
\end{align*}

For $\lambda>0$ the solution is
$$
y=A\cos\sqrt{\lambda}x+B\sin\sqrt{\lambda}x
$$

Hence $y^{\prime}\left(  x\right)  =-A\sqrt{\lambda}\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda
}x\right)  +B\sqrt{\lambda}\cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}x\right)  $. Applying
first B.C. gives

\begin{align}
-A\sqrt{\lambda}\sin\sqrt{\lambda}+B\sqrt{\lambda}\cos\sqrt{\lambda}%
+A\cos\sqrt{\lambda}+B\sin\sqrt{\lambda}  & =0\nonumber\\
B\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}\cos\sqrt{\lambda}+\sin\sqrt{\lambda}\right)  +A\left(
\cos\sqrt{\lambda}--\sqrt{\lambda}\sin\sqrt{\lambda}\right)    & =0\tag{1}
\end{align}

Applying second B.C. gives

\begin{equation}
0=A\tag{2}%
\end{equation}

Hence (1) becomes

\begin{align*}
B\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}\cos\sqrt{\lambda}+\sin\sqrt{\lambda}\right)    & =0\\
\tan\sqrt{\lambda}+\sqrt{\lambda}  & =0
\end{align*}

**Robin on left end:**

Finding eigenvalues for
\begin{align*}
y^{\prime\prime}+\lambda y  & =0\\
y^{\prime}\left(  0\right)  +y\left(  0\right)    & =0\\
y(1)  & =0
\end{align*}

Assuming $\lambda>0$ the solution is
$$
y=A\cos\sqrt{\lambda}x+B\sin\sqrt{\lambda}x
$$

Hence $y^{\prime}\left(  x\right)  =-A\sqrt{\lambda}\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda
}x\right)  +B\sqrt{\lambda}\cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}x\right)  $. Applying
first B.C. gives

\begin{equation}
B\sqrt{\lambda}+A=0\tag{1}
\end{equation}

Applying second B.C. gives

\begin{equation}
0=A\cos\sqrt{\lambda}+B\sin\sqrt{\lambda}\tag{2}
\end{equation}

From (1) $A=-B\sqrt{\lambda}$. Substituting this in (2) gives

\begin{align*}
0  & =-B\sqrt{\lambda}\cos\sqrt{\lambda}+B\sin\sqrt{\lambda}\\
0  & =B\left(  \sin\sqrt{\lambda}-\sqrt{\lambda}\cos\sqrt{\lambda}\right)
\end{align*}

$B$ can't be zero, else $A=0$ also and trivial solution. Hence we must have

\begin{align*}
\sin\sqrt{\lambda}-\sqrt{\lambda}\cos\sqrt{\lambda}  & =0\\
\tan\sqrt{\lambda}-\sqrt{\lambda}  & =0
\end{align*}

Comment: Robin b.c. defined in terms of normal to the boundary (why mma uses $\partial_n$ in it's documentation).  For region $[0,1]$ the normal to the region has different signs at values 0 and 1, as the normal to the region points in different directions in the 1-D space at these boundary values.  (c.f. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_boundary_condition) ).  It doesn't matter whether you place the sign inside or outside the `NeumannValue`, as long as one includes the *normal* direction.